# how to make view's scripts below layout's scripts

Tags: sails.js

how to using script block in layout

#### layout file:

```
<html>

-- styles files ---
  <body>
    <%- body %>  <!-- view content -->


   -- layout's scripts ---

  </body>
</html>
```

#### view file:

```
--- html tags ---
 view's scripts
```

=> i want view's scripts below layout's scripts but can't.
when i put script in layout, it is body, mean it will above of layout's scripts.

I don't known sailsjs have any way to define block like php laravel framework or not ? or any way to do it .

Thank you!

Comment: whats in the layout? navbar?what?, if you want it below, just make the css to make it

Answer (score 3):

This is not *exactly* possible using the default asset pipeline.

### Recommended workaround:

If you can, I'd actually recommend avoiding the issue altogether: instead, go in to your `tasks/pipeline.js` file and add the script you'd like to bring in there.  That does mean it will be included on *all* pages (as a script tag in development, and in the minified bundle in staging/production).  But in my experience, it is worth it for the clarity.  (Plus, keep in mind that in production, you'll probably want all your scripts in a single bundle-- or most of them anyway.)

[image: screenshot of tasks/pipeline.js]

### Another way:

If that still doesn't fit your needs, and you absolutely cannot have the script exist on other pages (e.g. because you're in post-production and are optimizing down the size of your bundle) then you can accomplish what you originally set out to do by modifying the Grunt tasks to support a different linker, or use another tool like Brunch, Webpack, or Gulp.

Or, if you (understandably) don't feel like customizing your Grunt tasks, then one other solution you might use is to add a script tag in `layout.ejs`, but wrap it in a conditional:

```
… (the automatically-injected scripts)
<script src="/dependencies/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="/js/utils/baz.js"></script>
<script src="/js/components/datepicker.component.js"></script>
<script src="/js/pages/foo/bar.page.js"></script>
<script src="/js/pages/beep/boop.page.js"></script>
… (etc)
<!--SCRIPTS END-->

<% if (view.path === 'pages/entrance/login') { %>
<!-- Additional script, since this is the login page: -->
<script>alert('hey!');</script>
<% } %>
```

> BTW, you can also use something like the above to conditionally include Google Analytics, etc. so you're not tracking test requests as actual production traffic -- just check the environment (that's what we do on the Sails website, for example).  This is also useful for conditionally including/omitting the robots/noindex meta tag (to prevent indexing duplicate content on your staging server), helpdesk chat widget, typekit, other analytics services, etc.
>
> [image: screenshot of conditionally adding either Google Analytics or robots noindex meta tag, depending on the hostname]

Comment: thank you, i will try with way check view path in layout file.